# Calling Magento API Script from Admin Backend

Tags: magento

Ive writte a little Magento API script which gets some order data and writes it to a *.csv file.

Is it possible to make it so that the scipt can be run from the Admin Backend? For example can I add a button to the Admin area that will run my script?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: yes you can but the question is: why do you need to call the function from an API. An API will call codes feom your Magento. So, why bother just call the codes directly without through the API

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible... but I don't think that will be the right approach. Could you elaborate a bit more in what needs do you have to get order information out of Magento by using the API?

If you are going to extract information out of Magento from another system then the API will be your best solution, but if in turn you have access to the admin try thinking other ways to get this job done without using the api.